# Column's value check through multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: Table1 and Table2.
They have 2 columns in common between them: ID, Name.

For the Name column they have same values: A, B and C.

I need to perform a check that after executing a SP they will have same IDs for a particular value in a Name column.
(Same IDs for A, Same IDs for B, Same IDs for C)

It is not a repetitive data. Table2 is a temporary table0 required by the process.

I know a way to do this but want to know whats the most efficient and simple way to do this.

Here is how I am doing it right now

```
DECLARE @Table1_id NVARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @Table2_id NVARCHAR(150)

SELECT @Table1_id = Tag_id FROM Tag WHERE Name = 'A'
SELECT @Table2_id  =  Tag_id FROM Tag_Imp WHERE Name = 'A'  

IF @Table1_id = @Table2_id
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Test Passed: ID of "A" is updated'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'Test Failed: ID of "A" is not updated'   

SELECT @Table1_id = Tag_id FROM Tag WHERE Name = 'B'
SELECT @Table2_id  = Tag_id FROM Tag_Imp WHERE Name = 'B'


IF @Table1_id = @Table2_id
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Test Passed: ID of "B" is updated'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'Test Failed: ID of "B" is not updated'   

SELECT @Table1_id = Tag_id FROM Tag WHERE Name = 'C'
SELECT @Table2_id  = Tag_id FROM Tag_Imp WHERE Name = 'C'


IF @Table1_id = @Table2_id
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Test Passed: ID of "C" is updated'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'Test Failed:ID of "C" is not updated'
```

Comment: the "best way" is to only store the Name in one table.  Duplicating data only causes sync problems like this.

Comment: "*know a way to do this*" can we see that please?

Comment: Can you show your solution of sample code, we can give our suggestions

Comment: This is a typical case of supertype-subtype relationship. Create a single table, move ID and Name columns there, reference it with FKs from all three of existing tables.

Comment: I edited my question to explain why I have not moved them in to a single table.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain how I am doing it right now.